# attribute different name to input radio in html table with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to ask you if you can help me to dynamiclly attribute ng-model name to an input radio in HTML table, using ng-repeat,

this my code

```
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-if="$index>0" ng-repeat="row in resultatfinal">
                    <td ng-repeat="k in  [] | range:collumnLength">{{ row [$index] }}</td>
                    <td ng-repeat="i in  [] | range:3"><input type="radio" ng-model="i" value="i" /> </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

i would like to attribut name like

```
    inputradio11 for the firt radio input in the first row
    inputradio12 for the firt radio input in the first row
    inputradio13 for the firt radio input in the first row

     inputradio21 for the firt radio input in the second row
```

thank you

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: if you resolve your problem, you can add your solution as answer, or delete question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution, i have juste used the id of the parent with $parent.$index to the indice of row, column indice i have the i var

```
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-if="$index>0" ng-repeat="row in resultatfinal">
                    <td ng-repeat="k in [] | range:collumnLength">{{ row [$index] }}</td>
                    <td ng-repeat="i in [] | range:3"><input type="radio" name="{{$parent.$index}}{{i}}" value="{{i}}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```